# set size wont work in java

Tags: java, swing

```
public void start_Gui() {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Client Program");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    window.setContentPane(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    JLabel leftside = new JLabel();
    leftside.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    JTextArea rightside = new JTextArea();
    rightside.setEditable(false);   //add scroll pane.
    rightside.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    rightside.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextArea client_text_input = new JTextArea();
    client_text_input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    leftside.add(client_text_input);

    JLabel buttons_layer = new JLabel();
    JButton login = new JButton("Login");
    JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
    buttons_layer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    buttons_layer.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    buttons_layer.add(login);
    buttons_layer.add(logout);
    leftside.add(buttons_layer);

    panel.add(leftside);
    panel.add(rightside);

    window.setSize(300, 400);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

I am working on a simple java chat client gui application. (the server etc, is done by others).

It is not a big project, but my only problem is that whatever I do to try to resize any components on the above GUI, won't work.

For example:

```
JTextArea client_text_input = new JTextArea();
client_text_input.setSize(100,200);
```

Won't work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Swing, you have two options for layout: do everything manually or let a `LayoutManager` handle it for you.

Calling `setSize()` will only work when you're not using a `LayoutManager`. Since you're using a `GridLayout` you'll have to use other ways to specify what you want.

Try calling [`setPreferredSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) and [`setMinimumSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29).

Answer (score 1):

Two things - firstly you should be setting the preferredSize of the scrollpane, but secondly, trying to resize it inside the componentResized handler isn't a very effective technique because the 'resized' events aren't continuous.

check [resizing text area in a JFrame](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=494250)

Answer (score 1):

but `setXxxSize` (for ContainersChilds) works as chaims if you change from `setSize()` (for TopLayoutContainer) to `setPreferredSize()` and you have to call `pack()` before `setVisible()`