# Change the height of a panel at runtime

Tags: java, swing, layout

How to change the height of panel at runtime?

I have some panels inside a `JFrame`, I tried on one of them:

```
int w = panel.getWidth();
panel.setSize(w, 1000);
```

But there's no effect. What's wrong?

Comment: Probably, you should rerender something, or the size of the panel is restrained by the size of one of the components the panel lives in. Can you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to [validate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) and repaint your panel. Try following:

```
int x=panel.getWidth();
panel.setSize(x,1000);
panel.validate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: invalidate would be safer unless the code is being guaranteed to be executed by the event dispatch thread

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:

[set size wont work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714214/set-size-wont-work-in-java)

"In Swing, you have two options for layout: do everything manually or let a LayoutManager handle it for you."

and

"Try calling setPreferredSize() and setMinimumSize()."

If you are using a layout manager (you probably are), the layout decides what to do with the 
contained components. setPreferredSize() usually works because the layout usually asks the
contained components what their preferred sizes are, and then arranges the components
based on (among others) that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the panel in a LayoutManager (i.e. the parent has a LayoutManager which is BorderLayout by default) that LayoutManager would override the size and thus your call would have no effect.

Try to call `setLayoutManager(null)` on the parent although I'd recommend using a LayoutManager and use `setPreferredSize()`, `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

For changing width and height of JPanel use **setPreferredSize** method.

```
JPanel folderPanel = new JPanel();      
folderPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(245, 450));// width, height
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set the visibility of this component (JPanel) as follow:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//set your custom size in this with=120; height=570;
panel.setSize(120,570);
panel.setVisible(false);
panel.setVisible(true);
//hope this help! :)
```