# why is this button still filling the whole frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have this code

```
package com.net.Forms;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainForm {

    protected static JFrame window = new JFrame("Test Form");
    protected static JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK!");

    public static void Main() {
        load();
        return;
    }
        public static void load() {
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
        //btnOK.setSize(50, 50); //here
        window.add(btnOK);
        btnOK.setEnabled(true);
        btnOK.setVisible(true);


        }

}
```

Why is the button still filling the frame instead of being 50 X 50 like i stated above

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read up on [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). That is the default layout manager for `JFrame`s.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714214/set-size-wont-work-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default Layout for `JFrame` is [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). That's why when you are adding a `JButton` to it , It is adding the `JButton` to the `center` and expanding it to cover entire window. `BorderLayout` doesn't respect the `setSize(..)` method of components being added to them. If you still want to give a preferred size to the component being added to `JFrame` you should change the layout to be [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) or [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or others.. and then use [`setPreferredSize(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) method with the component while adding it to the `JFrame`. For example Your code could be modified in following way.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainForm {

    protected  JFrame window = new JFrame("Test Form");
    protected  JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK!");

    public static void main(String st[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MainForm mf = new MainForm();
                mf.load();
            }
        });

    }
    public void load() {
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//Set layout to be FlowLayout explicitly.
    btnOK.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));//use set PreferredSize
    c.add(btnOK);
    c.setSize(500, 500);
    c.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod: So what you suggest in this case ?

Comment: Better to `pack()` the enclosing `Window` in order to _rely_ on the UI delegate's calculation. If you override `getPreferredSize()`, make the bounds no smaller to avoid [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Comment: So what you suggest in this case ? 1. create public method for GUI, to avoiding whatever inside main() 2. calling new MainForm() should be inside invokeLater. 3. all GUI creations in public MainForm() { should be ended window.setVisible(true);, 4. change ordering of code lines, 5. please don't put Xxx to JFrame, put there JPanel for this job 6. could be find out there, other 3-5 non_critical issues

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah I did that. But I had asked trashgod to suggest a way to achieve what OP wants without using `setPreferredSize`.

Answer (score -2):

Its just a bug or sth.
the last element added to frame Takes Whole of it.

all you need to do :
declare a new simple component like JLabel()
add it to frame.
Dont set Bounds Or Size For it.just a new Label.
MAKE SURE that this label is the last element added to frame.
Hope it Works.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please take a look at the [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.  There is already a very detailed answer to this question that was accepted 4+ years ago.  Your answer unfortunately does not provide any additional information that would help OP or the public researching this issue.